# define variable labels in a loop for existing variables SPSS

Tags: loops, variables, label, spss

I have some variables

V1
V2
V3

which I want to give variable labels in a Loop:

```
variable labels V1 "Person 1".
variable labels V2 "Person 2".
...
```

Should be an easy thing, but as far as I could see I cannot use DO REPEAT (because it's no data transformation) but have to write a macro.

(see: [How can I loop through variables in SPSS? I want to avoid code duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884479/how-can-i-loop-through-variables-in-spss-i-want-to-avoid-code-duplication))

Coming from R and STATA I really have difficulty of seeing how to start.

The answer to this question:
[Variable labels in SPSS Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014557/variable-labels-in-spss-macro)
seems different to me since new variables are created and not existing variables relabeled.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SPSS Python Integration Package installed you can run a loop in Python.

The following code creates the lines `variable labels V# "Person #".` Where '#' is a number from 1 to 3.

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss

for i in range(1, 4):
    spss.Submit('variable labels V%s "Person %s".' % (i, i))
END PROGRAM.
```